# Show that $G$ has $\frac{p+3}{2}$ different conjugation classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is from a previous exam paper, several exercises have already been completed, and their results are given here since they are often used in the subsequent exercises.

#### Pre-exercise:

We have $G$, which is a non-abelian group of order $2p$, where $p$ is an odd prime.

---

#### Results from exercise 1

$G$ has a normal subgroup $P$ of order $p$. $G$ consists of the neutral element $e$, plus $p$ elements of order $2$ and $p-1$ elements of order $p$.

---

#### Results from exercise 2

We have shown that $x \in G$ where $ord(x)=2$ has a centralizer $Z(x)$, where $|Z(x)|=2$. Furthermore $y \in P$ with $ord(y)=p$ has centralizer with order $|Z(y)|=p$.

---

#### The exercise I'm needing help with is as follows:

"Show that $G$ has $\frac{p+3}{2}$ different conjugation classes".

The explanatory answer says:

"From the previous exercise, we see that the number of elements in the conjugation class for an element $p$ is $\frac{|G|}{p}=2$, so that there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ conjugation classes consisting of elements of order $p$".

I do not understand how we can use information about the centralizer in order to obtain information about the number of conjugation classes. What information from exercise 2 (or 1?) can be used to conclude the above?

**It continues:**

"Additionally we see that there are $\frac{|G|}{2}=p$ elements in the conjugation class for an element of order 2. Together with the conjugation class $\{e\}$ we get $\frac{p-1}{2}+1+1=\frac{p+3}{2}$ different conjugation classes."

This final step would appear to make sense, but I do not see why we "see" that there are $\frac{|G|}{2}=p$ elements in the conjugation class for elements of order 2. Does this also follow directly from something shown previously?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $\;G\times G\to G\;,\;\;g\cdot x:=x^g=g^{-1}xg\;$ is an action of $\;G\;$ on itself, and thus by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, for any $\;x\in G\;$:

$$|\mathcal O(x)|=[G:G_x]\;,\;\;G_x:=\{g\in G\;|\;g\cdot x:=x^g=x\}=C_G(x)=\text{the centralizer of}\;x$$

in the whole group $\;G\;$

Can you take it from here?